# Knowing the type of VoIP application carried by H.323

Tags: sip, voip, h.323

I know that H.323 can be used for VoIP applications such as T.38 (fax over IP). Are there any fields within the H.323 packets that indicate the type of VoIP applications carried? Something similar to the SIP messages where we can find the string "t38"?

Answer (score 1):

In case of T38, you can find some hints inside h245 protocol(like "application t38fax"), please check link below for more info:

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/voice/h323/118726-technote-h323-00.html#anc1